# Creating a dynamic selector in on() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the `on()` event to handle dynamically created code. It works when the selector is hard coded in the `on()` event.

I would like to be able to have it select different elements based on which box they select.

```
$("body").on("change", $("#"+$(this).attr("id")) ,function()
```

When I run this the selector is undefined. Is there any way to make the selector dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

When delegating events, jQuery generally expects the second argument in `on()` to be a string, as it's used as a filter internally etc.

Meaning, just pass the string instead of a jQuery collection

```
$("body").on("change", "#" + this.id, function() { ...
```

Of course, it makes very little sense to delegate to the body, filtering on an ID etc, when you already have the element you're targeting in `this`

```
$(this).on("change", function() { ...
```